# Gradle 2.5 Experimental : include .so library and call from JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My problem is that I fail to find some proper documents/guides to follow in order to set up my environment correctly.

Basically I am using Android Studio 1.3.2 (latest stable as of 22nd september 2015) with Gradle Experimental version 2.5.

I followed Google official documentation here : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental but I find no help when it comes to JNI Libs. I tried many other solutions but they do not work because they seem to be obsolete.

I have a **.so** file of a simple **C++ library** I created to test the NDK support & integration that should be better with this Android Studio 1.3 as announced during Google I/O 2015.

This is how looks my very simple `C++ Lib`:

Content of TestCPPClass.h

```
#ifndef TESTCPPCLASS_H
#define TESTCPPCLASS_H

class TestCPPClass {
public:
    double getDouble();
};

#endif TESTCPPCLASS_H
```

And TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "TestCPPClass.h"  

double TestCPPClass::getDouble()
{
    return 1; // cannot be dumber ! ^^
}
```

Using **Cygwin terminal** and **gcc** I compiled this very advanced library using the following line :

> gcc.exe -shared -o TestLib.so TestCPPClass.cpp

Which did correctly produce a `TestLib.so`.

In my current Android project, I have a **native** method that is implemented in JNI as followed :

`public static double getDoubleFromJNI();`

Using **javah.exe** I generated the **.h** file and then implemented the JNI method as follow :

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "my_package_header.h"
#include "TestCPPClass.h" // => MARKED AS RED because not found ?

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_my_package_header_getDoubleFromJNI
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject caller)
{
     // Here I wish to call my TestLib.so that should contain my TestCPPClass and call "TestCPPClass::getDouble()"
     // in order to return the result.
}
```

So what about my **build.gradle** ?
This is what I have for NDK inside `model{}`

```
android.ndk {
        moduleName = "MyAwesomeJNI"
        ldLibs += "TestLib" => gradle SYNC works, but BUILD fails !
    }
```

This is the error I get :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:linkArm64-v8aDebugMyAwesomeJNISharedLibrary'.
>
> > A build operation failed.
> >           Linker failed while linking libMyAwesomeJNI.so.   See the complete log at:
> >     file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/MyProject/app/build/tmp/linkArm64-v8aDebugMyAwesomeJNISharedLibrary/output.txt

I manually created the **jniLibs** folder alongside **jni** using `New > directory`. I also added a **armeabi** folder and put **TestLib.so** inside. I tried without `armeabi` but with no luck.

What am I missing here ? I am totally lost! Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use a prebuilt library if you wish, but you can also compile your **TestClass.cpp**, both with the *experimental* plugin.

Comment: @AlexCohn as my post says, I already attempted the solution using a compiled shared library (prebuilt as you says) but the issue lies whithin the linking that does not occur at compile time, hence the problem where my library is never detected at all therefore not usable.

Comment: I cannot see your **build.gradle**, but I believe that the problem is exactly in mixing the two approaches. If the issue is still relevant, I could probably help you find the way out. I believe it will be easier to do in the interactive chat window.

Comment: What does your **build.gradle** look like?  We need to know how you specified repositories...

Answer (score -1):

Have a look on the following guide:
http://www.shaneenishry.com/blog/2014/08/17/ndk-with-android-studio/
I also struggle with the .so files but I think you are missing the following:

android {

```
// .. android settings ..

sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/myCppLibraries' // <-- Set your folder here!
}
```

}

You are right looks like there is change between 2.4 and 2.5
The following configuration works to me as I try to work with OpenCL & Andriod:
build.gradle (app)
...

```
android.ndk{
moduleName = ""
ldLibs +=["android", "log", "OpenCL"]
cppFlags+="-I${file("src/main/jniLibs/")}".toString()
ldFlags += "-L${file("src/main/jniLibs/")}".toString()
}
```

...

application structure:

```
app
-src
--main
---java
---jni
----test.c
---jniLibs
----libOpenCL.so
```

Using gradle-experimental:0.2.0

Comment: Thank you but this article is not up to date with Gradle new syntaxes. Following http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental, I tried to add : http://pastebin.com/ipVy8jzi but it sill fails

Comment: Alright, it seems to start working but I am still no there yet. Have a look to my gradle file (a part of it anyway) : http://pastebin.com/F2DResdv and now have a look to my CPP file : http://pastebin.com/2XizuFcE and of course, compilation fails : `Error:(6, 26) TestCppClass.h: No such file or directory` so it still does not work :/ and by the way I have to use `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-all.zip` in my  **gradle-wrapper.properties** file